# Netlogo IF statement, Excepted TRUE/FALSE here, rather than a list or block

Tags: netlogo

I have an error message in the if statement says "Excepted TRUE/FALSE here, rather than a list or block".
I'm curious about why it gives this error and how to solve it !
I want to compare the position of the ball on the field with a position to do something.
My code is

```
ask balls [ 
    fd 5 
    if[ [xcor] of ball 1 = 4 ] [
      ;;do something
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
ask balls [ 
    fd 5 
    if [xcor] of ball 1 = 4 [
      ;;do something
    ]
  ]
```

You don't need the `[]` around the condition you are testing and the `[]` is a signal to NetLogo that the contents are a list or a block, hence the error message.

Just looking at your code generally, I think you really want:

```
ask balls [ 
    fd 5 
    if xcor = 4 [
      ;;do something
    ]
  ]
```

This will test the `xcor` of each ball, rather than the `xcor` of ball number 1. The way you have the code set up, then all balls will 'do something' when ball 1 is at the specified x-coordinates and no ball will 'do something' when it's not.